# Check if the user is attached or not yet

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with **Laravel** on little project, i have a pivot table and I would like to attach new users, but I must check if the user is not already attached. how can I do ?

```
$user = User::findOrFail(2);
$user->liked()->attach(6);
dd($user);
```

How can I check if the user number 6 is already attached or not, so i can add the new record.

Comment: This Will help https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use the `sync` method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(2);
$user->liked()->sync([6,//ids you want attach]);


dd($user);
```

If you do not want to detach existing IDs that are missing from the given array, you may use the syncWithoutDetaching method:

```
$user->liked()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);
```

[Also Refer This](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)